# Javascript - How to get and use the value?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm learning React a lot from example, so my javascript basic is not very good.
I'm actually a network engineer but I try to learn to do the javascript programming.
OK, I try to implement IoT project from Viktor Kirilov (https://github.com/deepsyx).
I have the following code and get the output from console.log but I cannot display it in the browser. How can I display the result in the browser?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const getTemperature = require('./utils/temperature');

function getTemp() {
  setInterval(() => {
    getTemperature().then((temperature) => {
      temperature;
      console.log(temperature);
    });
  }, 1000);
};

var temp = getTemp();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(temp);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

utils/temperature.js

```
const exec = require('child_process').execSync;
const fs = require('fs');

exec('modprobe w1-gpio');
exec('modprobe w1-therm');

const DEVICES_DIR = '/sys/bus/w1/devices';

const files = fs.readdirSync(DEVICES_DIR);
const deviceFolder = files.find(file => /^28/.test(file));
const deviceFile = DEVICES_DIR + '/' + deviceFolder + '/w1_slave';

function getTemperature () {
  const readFilePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(deviceFile, 'utf8', (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
  return readFilePromise.then(file => {
    const lines = file.split('\n');
    if (lines[0].substr(-3) !== 'YES') {
      throw new Error('Temperature device not connected');
    }
    const tempString = lines[1].split('t=')[1].trim();

    return parseFloat(tempString) / 1000.0;
  });
}

module.exports = getTemperature;
```

The result from server:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/emotion $ node server.js 
Example app listening at http://localhost:3000
26.437
26.5
26.437
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.562
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.5
26.562
26.687
26.75
26.937
```

Comment: you need to create a route in express and then copy paste the url in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just posting the relevant code that may help you solving this issue.

```
  async function getTemp(res) {
    await getTemperature()
     .then((temperature) => {
       res.send(JSON.stringify(temperature))
     })
     .catch(error => console.log(error))
 
  }
   
  app.get('/', async (_req, res) => {
    await getTemp(res);
  });
```

1. You can safely remove the `temp` variable that calls the function `getTemp()` from within the middleware. This variable is redundant.
2. call `getTemp()` directly passing in the response object.
3. Inside the `getTemp(res)` async function, `await` for the temperature.
4. Once the promise resolves, send the stringified response. If the promise fails, you log the error within the catch block.

Does **this** help ?

Comment: Thank you very much, first res.send(temperature) -> I get the error and after you change to JSON.stringify(temperature) it display correctly. This helps me a lot!!!

Comment: Next step I will try with socketio, thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help my friend :)